# How to get eigenvectors from Linear Discriminant Analysis with scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

How can one obtain the change-of-basis matrix from a scikit-learn linear discriminant analysis object?

For an array `X` with shape `m x p` (`m` samples and `p` features) and `N` classes, the scaling matrix has `p` rows and `N-1` columns. This matrix can be used to transform the data from the original space to the linear subspace.

---

EDITED after Arya's answer:

Let's consider the following example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA

X, label = make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features=2, centers=5, cluster_std=0.10, random_state=0)
lda = LDA()
Xlda = lda.fit(X, label)
Xlda.scalings_
#array([[ 7.35157288,  6.76874473],
#       [-6.45391558,  7.97604449]])
Xlda.scalings_.shape
#(2, 2)
```

I would expect the scalings_ matrix shape to be (2,4) as I have 2 features and the LDA would provide 5-1 components.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call your `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` object `lda`. You can access the scaling matrix as `lda.scalings_`. The documentation that describes this is shown [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis).

```
import sklearn.datasets as ds
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA

iris = ds.load_iris()
iris.data.shape
# (150, 4)
len(iris.target_names)
# 3

lda = LDA()
lda.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
lda.scalings_
# array([[-0.81926852,  0.03285975],
#        [-1.5478732 ,  2.15471106],
#        [ 2.18494056, -0.93024679],
#        [ 2.85385002,  2.8060046 ]])
lda.scalings_.shape
# (4, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind interest. It is true that for the iris data set  it seems to work ok (the results are different from those that I would obtain from R though but I guess it is due to some normalizing preprocessing.) Nevertheless, for a different example, the scaling_ matrix fails to meet the previous requirements on its shape, see my answer using make_blobs.


`

Comment: I edited my question in order to show an example where the shape of scaling_ matrix seems to be wrong.

Comment: This would be worth submitting an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/new) to scikit-learn's maintainers.

Comment: Issue added: [link to issue on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8956)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy in this example, the lda.scalings_ are the eigenvectors?

Comment: no, the scalings_ are not the eigenvectors, as mentioned by Alex Gramfort on the sklearn mailing list, "it stores the direction of the decision function to match the API of
linear models."